# Group/Cluster K-Fold Cross-Validation

Tags: clustering, cross-validation, python, scikit-learn

I need to do a K-fold CV on some models, but I need to ensure the validation (test) data set is clustered together by a group and `t` number of years. `GroupKFold` is close, but it still splits up the validation set (see second fold).

For example, if I have a set of data with years from 2000-2008 and I want to K-fold into 3 groups. The appropriate sets would be: Validation: 2000-2002, Train: 2003-2008; V:2003-2005, T:2000-2002 & 2006-2008; and V: 2006-2008, T: 2000-2005).

Is there a way to group and cluster the data using K-Fold CV where the validation set is clustered by `t` years?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupKFold

X = [0.1, 0.2, 2.2, 2.4, 2.3, 4.55, 5.8, 8.8, 9, 10, 0.1, 0.2, 2.2]
y = ["a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "a", "b", "b"]
groups = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]

gkf = GroupKFold(n_splits=2)
for train_index, test_index in gkf.split(X, y, groups=groups):
    print("Train:", train_index, "Validation:",test_index)
```

Output:

```
Train: [ 0  1  2  3  4  5 10 11 12] Validation: [6 7 8 9]
Train: [3 4 5 6 7 8 9] Validation: [ 0  1  2 10 11 12]
Train: [ 0  1  2  6  7  8  9 10 11 12] Validation: [3 4 5]
```

Comment: Have you looked at TimeSeriesSplit? An example is at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation-of-time-series-data

Comment: @sebp That is close, but I also need a group of years and the rest of the data, not sure the previous set. I am trying to avoid writing a custom function, but looks like I might be heading that route. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why rely on a function named "cross validation"?

Just split your data explicitly as desired, by **selecting the year ranges that you want**. It is not required to do this using a black box built-in (plus, the built-in would likely perform random sampling and not temporal slicing).

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing. I asked the question to see if there was a name for the CV method or a simple function.